Parallel use of gerund phrases and noun phrases

She is not only a good teacher but also being a good leader.

Do you think this sentence is correct?
I think it would make sense to consider the gerund phrase as a noun phrase.
(I think I've heard this type of thing a lot.)

You have? I could imagine more likely casual examples ("She's not only CEO of two different nonprofits, but also killing it as a mother"), but for formal usage, expecting "is" to do double duty as an independent verb and a helping verb is expecting too much and borders on paraprosdokian.

Wouldn't it be simpler just to leave out 'being'?

Hm, actually I have a nice simple counter argument to myself: "She is awake and making breakfast." That seems reasonable

Of course, it isn't as constrained by the "not only __ but __" construction that enforces an extra level of parallelism.

@AndyBonner: I don't see anything wrong with "She is not only awake but also making breakfast." Good example!

@PhilSweet: I don't think the passival is relevant here; the passival was the use of the construction "is Xing" to mean "is being Xed", whereas in the OP's example there's no "Xed".

yes, I realized that after I posted. But for some reason related to focus, I find all "is being" uses terrible.

Maybe a better example would use something like, "She is a good teacher and becoming a good leader"?  This also sounds clumsy, but isn't so simply corrected.

You can’t expect your is to function as both a copula and an auxiliary; you need is twice. She is a good teacher and is being a good leader.

@TinfoilHat Why use "being" at all? Doesn't "she is a good teacher and a good leader" mean exactly the same thing?  If you want to express that this is a recent phenomenon, then "she is a good teacher and has become a good leader."

@nasch — That’s an edit of style. Great, but it doesn’t really address the OP’s struggle.

I suggest that sentence could be justified, but never in the hugely limited context. There might be a dozen justifications but without more clues, aren't they all speculation? Isn't it more  useful to ask where the example came from, why Korean thought it could be correct and perhaps more importantly, where one might hear 'this type of thing' a lot? Come to that, what is 'this type of thing'? May we have other examples?

@TinfoilHat That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Is there any reason you want to use is being in this sentence? The sentence would have the same meaning and much more parallelism if you used:

She is not only a good teacher but also a good leader.

I don't see why you want to use "is being" here rather than simply "is".

If you want to convey the fact that she is currently leading well, you could say "She not only is a good teacher but also is leading well". I wouldn't use "She is not only a good teacher but also leading well".

What about: "She is not only being a good teacher but also being a good leader [during the recent outbreak of plague]"? To me, this implies these actions are happening "more in the moment" and may be time limited.

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language (CGEL) distinguishes six usages of 'be'  in addition to the existential usage:


Copula (be + subjective predicative complement): She was a lawyer.
Progressive (be + -ing participle): She was sleeping.

...

Using two distinct usages of be after a single subject ( eg She is [a good teacher] and [being a good leader]) is syllepsis, and often better avoided.
Some of these syllepses are far worse than others:

You were seen and not to be seen.
He has been a great help and to Paris.

Here, the original is arguably not ungrammatical, but using a simple tweak is better, stylistically at least:

Not only is she a good teacher, but she is proving to be a good leader as well.


How is "seen and not to be seen" a bad syllepsis? Or is it an example of a good one?

Fronting "not only" definitely opens up more possibilities. But even with a strong pragmatic tie,  it doesn't seem to quite work. not only is she a good teacher, but also is getting her masters.  I suspect gapping rules have led this to be poorly formed because it would knock out other constructions or mean juggling too many options for too long. Even verbs such as training that are inherently progressive don't pass the smell test. not only is she a good teacher, but also is training for a marathon. (least bad to my ears, but still awkward.)

'You were seen and not to be seen' incongruously twins two very different usages of 'be', the passive auxiliary (am/is/was... seen) and the 'quasi-modal' (≈must) ('You are not to tell anyone'). It's nearly as bad as 'he declined their offer and ten Latin nouns.' As Peter Shor states above, parallelism is very important in English constructions.

I'd use a semicolon and two independent clauses with these. 'She's a good teacher; not only this, she is also getting her masters'

"He has been a great help and to Paris" is hilarious!


She is not only a good teacher but also being a good leader.

If the evident ellipsis is not used we get what follows.

She is not only a good teacher but she is  also being a good leader.

The use of the progressive with "be" is exceptional. In this case there is no context that permits "is being".
Otherwise, if we conceive the sentence as not being constructed on the basis of an ellipsis, the part "but also being a good leader" is an incomplete construction.
Here are two possibilities that makes this sentence correct.

She is not only a good teacher but also,  being a good leader, she can make things run smoothly.

She is not only a good teacher but also, being a good leader, she is an asset in the school administration.



Let me add a note. There is absolutely nothing wrong with using is being in general. Some of the best stylists in English have used it. Jane Austen: “My dear aunt, this is being serious indeed.” Pat Conroy: "He was being more cautious now that he knew we were aware that he was following us." And this answer gives the impression that you should avoid using is being altogether; it doesn't explain when to use it. Once you figure out the difference between is and is being, you should certainly feel free to use it.

@PeterShor On the contrary, I think that there is much to say against this use. Jane Austen has used it, yes, but are we sure of what Jane Austen had in mind? Wasn't there some connotation, the insinuation that the aunt was slightly overdoing it for instance? This is exactly the type of connotation you find usually when the progressive is used with "to be". The grammar I used is formal: the progressive is inimical to the verb "to be". The use of "is being" is the subject of another question and I remember haveng provided the grammar on it in some answer.

@PeterShor Let me rather give you the exact words found in that grammar, as I checked them just now: "the observation that stative verb meanings are inimical to the idea that some phenomenon is 'in progress'".

If a grammar book tells you one thing and some of the better stylists in the English language do something different, who do you think is correct? (Although in this case, the authors seem to do it quite rarely, and only in certain circumstances, so it might be a good idea to think twice before going contrary to the grammar book.)

@PeterShor  I happen to believe that  great grammars in a language are fairly trustworthy. // There are exceptions; for instance, "Volitional subjuncts can often occur with copular verbs if (i) the adjective as complement is being used dynamically, or (ii) if the noun-phrase complement implies activity, or (iii) if there is a space adjunct:
He is being foolish intentionally.
He is being a nuisance deliberately. " . However, something like "He is being in the next room." is unthinkable.

@PeterShor: FWIW, I don't think your Jane Austen example works in present-day English; I wouldn't point to it as a model. (But your Pat Conroy example is perfectly normal usage.)

@PeterShor, those examples have being with an adjective; a closer analogue with the sentence we're studying would be something like "Henry is being Erica's supervisor today".
